# Automatic type resolving for generics

Tags: typescript

I want to define an interface for a table column with the following properties:

- title: the title of the column
- key: the key of a property in a specific model (so I can get the value)
- valueFormatter: any function to format the value which returns a string

The valueFormatter-Function should get a parameter, which has the same type as the property (key). So something like this.

```
export interface Column<T, P extends keyof T> {
  label: string;
  key: P;
  valueFormatter?: (value: T[P]) => string
};
```

Is there any way to use this in another interface without explicit define the "P" type like this:

```
export interface Table<T> {
  data: T[];
  columns: Column<T>[];
}
```

Or: how can I define the Column Interface without the P-Generic and be safe with "key" and "valueFormatter"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I'd be inclined to make `columns` an object with one property per key of `T`, since you presumably don't want to risk missing one of the columns:

```
interface Column<T, P extends keyof T> {
  label: string;
  key: P;
  valueFormatter?: (value: T[P]) => string;
}

interface TableWithColumnObject<T> {
  data: T[];
  columnObject: { [K in keyof T]: Column<T, K> };
}
```

There `columnObject` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), and you'd use it like this:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const table1: TableWithColumnObject<Person> = {
  data: [{ name: "Alice", age: 35 }, { name: "Bob", age: 38 }],
  columnObject: {
    name: {
      label: "Name",
      key: "name",
      valueFormatter: name => name
    },
    age: {
      label: "Age",
      key: "age",
      valueFormatter: age => "" + age
    }
  }
};
```

If you don't care about missing one of the columns (or maybe you *want* to be able to miss some of the columns or include duplicates) then you can get your desired type by using the `columnObject` mapped type in a slightly more complicated way:

```
interface TableWithColumnArray<T> {
  data: T[];
  columnArray: { [K in keyof T]: Column<T, K> }[keyof T][];
}
```

Here we've taking the mapped type, and [looked up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) its properties, and said we want an array of those.  So for `Person`, that type looks like `Array<Column<Person, "name"> | Column<Person, "age">>`.  And we use it like this:

```
const table2: TableWithColumnArray<Person> = {
  data: [{ name: "Alice", age: 35 }, { name: "Bob", age: 38 }],
  columnArray: [
    {
      label: "Name",
      key: "name",
      valueFormatter: name => name
    },
    {
      label: "Age",
      key: "age",
      valueFormatter: age => "" + age
    }
  ]
};
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsA2BXAtiAHgBUAaZABWQgA9IQATAZ2QGsIBPdGZIgPmQDeAKGTJMcAEYRMALmSMwUUAHMA3CNYc55daIBucHBABi6KLjhhIUAPxyAFAaNyiAbXIBdAJTIAvPwUlEDUhAF8hIVBreCQeSUwIAHVgMAALDBx8AHkJACsIBDBifmFReks4F1cPXWQELDwQHPzCuQFkVwBpZFBNTm4iDzkMxuIyTv5Q9XDI8GgYlHJoRnQQQQ0QOFwIOUCVWrhlHeQQPCkoaYj6kAVkMHiIAEYXB+S0key8gqKlqBWQfi+dZlCpyVztTbbOQAIgAgphgEhoWRDscAMwAVmQoTIEK2x2hACF0BJkchUXI0QAObEeEgaeqZJpfVrA0QnfFtDTssSSaQwgBy+OR3PZbHYMMhEBFPP0hmwJjMFis0DkUr8-ClopxoopbJ54iksmQcKOMtl4phqPNPKcCtM5ks1jkqI1JuhyAA1OSjtqNOEphEovNECgiK8UukGvhYVAoHB2MU2eV7lUagzoyBY-GJYIOt1euKuDwhmhM2NkBNsa4iwMPNVLkJrrd7hIEgAmF5tpKRj5ZuMJgi-f6A5Ogjp4qEm+GI6Uoo6UrE4vNSmHE0nz9E00J0jNM7MJsGi0qyw38k1C7Y2sVaE1S69yowO5XOjnbN1ank6nkng1842mnOoqiJaJrWvSsrIHaiqOiqUAukcbrQh63qon6ogeGE6hAA)

Comment: Thanks for this very good and detailed answer. I'd go with the second approach in case I don't always want to be forced to define every column for the given data array. Do you have any further informations about the syntax? Especially why I have to define all properties on columnObject if I omit '[keyof T][]'?

Comment: The type `{ [K in keyof T]: Column<T, K> }` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) with the same keys as `T` but the property types are mapped.  If we use a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) on the `keyof T` property (so `{...}[keyof T]`), that is the union of all those properties.  And then if we suffx that type with `[]`, we are saying we want an array of those.

Comment: Assuming `T` is `Person`, `{ [K in keyof T]: Column<T, K> }` becomes `{name: Column<Person, "name">; age: Column<Person, "age"}`.  And then `{ [K in keyof T]: Column<T, K> }[keyof T]` becomes `Column<Person, "name"> | Column<Person, "age">`.  And then `{ [K in keyof T]: Column<T, K> }[keyof T][]` becomes `Array<Column<Person, "name"> | Column<Person, "age">>`, which is what you want.  If you leave off `[keyof T][]` you are left with the mapped type, which requires named keys.